Logout from Next.js Middleware When Refresh Token Expires (Auth.js)
I'm implementing authentication using Auth.js, and so far, things are going smoothly.
However, i have a question about handling expired refresh tokens.
I currently have a solution where, in the jwt callback, i attempt to refresh the access token. If the refresh token has expired, i set an error message in the session. Inside the middleware, i can access this message and, if it’s present, redirect the user to a client page indicating that their session has expired. From that client page, i call Auth.js signOut method, then redirect the user to the login page.
I’d like to know is there a way to logout the users directly from the middleware, when the refresh token expires, and redirect them to the login page with the session expiration message, without redirecting them to a separate client page that calls signOut?
I know i can delete the token Auth.js cookies in the middleware, and this works, but is that the right approach?
Thanks :)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Trigger signOut method in a common component like header
